# How do i call external javascript function/lines in html?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In the javascript file i have this code:

```
    $(function() {

    $('#carousel span').append('<img src="img/gui/carousel_glare.png" class="glare" />');
    $('#thumbs a').append('<img src="img/gui/carousel_glare_small.png" class="glare" />');
    $('#carousel').carouFredSel({
        responsive: true,
        circular: false,
        auto: true,
                infinite: true,
        items: {
            visible: 1,
            width: 200,
            height: '56%'
        },
        scroll: {
            fx: 'directscroll',
                        pauseOnHover: true,
                        duration: 500
        }
    });

    $('#thumbs').carouFredSel({
        responsive: true,
        circular: false,
        infinite: false,
        auto: false,
        prev: '#prev',
        next: '#next',
        items: {
            visible: {
                min: 2,
                max: 6
            },
            width: 150,
            height: '66%'
        }
    });

    $('#thumbs a').click(function() {
        $('#carousel').trigger('slideTo', '#' + this.href.split('#').pop() );
        $('#thumbs a').removeClass('selected');
        $(this).addClass('selected');
        return false;
    });

});
```

I want that when the pauseOnHover execute that something will happen in the html file.
In the html file i included the javascript file already:

```
<script src="java_script.js"></script>
```

Also added some style code for the test:

```
<style>.container {
    background: rgb(170, 187, 97);
    background: rgba(170, 187, 97, 0.5);
}</style>
```

And when the pauseOnHover execute happen in the javascript file i want to display on screen this two lines in the html file:

```
<div class="container">Lorem ipsum dolor</div>
<div class="container">Lorem ipsum_for_testing dolor</div>
```

Comment: Is `pauseOnHover` working for you?

Comment: That could have been done if `carouFredSel` had an callback function.

Comment: }); is missing in the last

Comment: find out if there are any callback function that can be used on pauseonhover. Basically with the function you execute your set of statements when the pauseon hover happens. if you could share the name of the libray that you are using. it might be helpful

Comment: Manwal it does working.

Comment: suchit i know i just added the top part of the javascript code where the pauseOnHover is.

Comment: The jquery is this: http://coolcarousels.frebsite.nl/c/28/ in my project on netbeans i added the css in external file and the javascript in external file. And in the html i'm calling the files the css and javascript files.

Comment: This is my jsfiddler: http://jsfiddle.net/5hrn1nop/ i want this to work on the big images not the small ones.